# java spring BCryptPasswordEncoder "SecureRandom random" constructor parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, bcrypt

Can you please explain what means `SecureRandom random` parameter in class `org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder`?

Javadoc is here: [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.html)

And I ask about this constructor: `BCryptPasswordEncoder(int strength, SecureRandom random)`. I can't understand what parameter `SecureRandom random` means.

I've tried to read spring documentation or find something in google, but I still don't understand it's purpose. I know that bCrypt always add some random salt to password, but as I see from the sources of `BCrypt` class, it is not the same.

Comment: It is random number generator and spring security allows this in contructor   because you can specify custom configuration for random number for this.  refer this    https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as it says from the javadoc for `SecureRandom` it is an object containing a random number that you can use to randomize the hashes that the `BCryptPasswordEncoder` generates.

Here is what the javadoc for the class states:

> A cryptographically strong random number minimally complies with the statistical random number generator tests specified in FIPS 140-2, Security Requirements for Cryptographic Modules, section 4.9.1.

For an example of how to create a SecureRandom here is another quote from the documentation:

> Typical callers of SecureRandom invoke the following methods to retrieve random bytes:

```
  SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
  byte bytes[] = new byte[20];
  random.nextBytes(bytes);
```

> Callers may also invoke the generateSeed method to generate a given number of seed bytes (to seed other random number generators, for example):

```
  byte seed[] = random.generateSeed(20);
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the bean as follows (strength 11 and SecureRandom as salt)

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11, new SecureRandom());
}
```